# Search an array of selectors and return matching index

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a keyboard navigation function.

```
<li class="icon"></li>
<li class="icon open"></li>
<li class="icon"></li>
<li class="icon open active"></li>
<li class="icon"></li>
<li class="icon open"></li>
```

I want to have it so that pressing the left or up arrow selects the ".open" list item before ".active" and the right or down arrow selects the ".open" list item after ".active"

I'm using this:

```
var openArray = $('li.open');
```

to build an array which returns this:

```
<li class="icon open"></li>
<li class="icon open active"></li>
<li class="icon open"></li>
```

My next step is to find the index of the ".active" list item inside openArray but that's where I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to search through an array of selectors and return its index. I read through the documentation for .grep() and .inArray() and .index() and .find() and everything I could think of (including the tree traversal methods) but I can't get any combination of them working.

My next step after that will be to navigate through the array using the index and .length. That part will be no problem but I can't get to it without knowing the '.active' index.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use each to iterate over the array and return the index of the "active" element

```
var openArray = $('li.open');

$(openArray).each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active") ) {
        console.log("found" + " " + index);
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var active = $("li .active").eq(0);
active.parent().index( active );


   // Try this so:

var i = 0;
var index = -1;
arraySelector.each(function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
     {
          index = i;
     }
     ++i;
});
```

Does this work? :)

Comment: I have no problem selecting '.active'. My problem is filtering an array of selectors by class and then returning the filtered item's index

Comment: active.parent().index(active) will give you the index of the li

Comment: You want the index relative to the selector array or the ul?

Comment: Relative to the selector array yeah. In openArray I can see that '.active' has an index of 1 but I can't figure out how to find that by searching the array using '.active'

Comment: i'am not native english speaker and i am sorry to not understand what your trouble is.

Comment: In my example use .hasClass("active") is kind of '.active'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.next()`

```
var active = $('li.icon.open.active');
var prevIcon = active.next('.icon.open');
```

Comment: "You need to use `.prev()`", But use the `next()`? :)

Comment: If you use $('li.icon.open.active') it selects the active list item but when you use .next('.icon.open') it will only return a value if the next item in the list contains the specified classes. It doesn't appear to search until it finds the next matching element, it just checks the next one. In my case it may be the next one or it may skip 3 or 4 list items until there's another '.open'

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried the suggestions but either I didn't make the problem clear in my initial question or the answer isn't as obvious as people think. I found a solution and here's how I did it:

Instead of dumping the selectors into an array and worrying about searching through that I put their indexes in an array

```
var openArray = [];
var activeIndex;
var i = 0;
$.each($('#tbul li.icon'), function(index, value) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        openArray.push(index);
        i++;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        activeIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Using this I dump all the open list items into openArray and I know where the active list item is in that array using activeIndex.

I was hoping for a pretty jQuery solution (and I'm sure it exists) but this will do for now

Comment: this ia a little bit round-a-bout. Your initial idea was correct and you can simply get the array by using a selector. see my answer.